# Android: List that scrolls horizontal with one row and two columns

Tags: android, size, android-recyclerview

I need to do a horizontal scroller where each ViewHolder has the same size but it size is half of the screen.
Let me show you what I've done:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aru4S.png

The red square is an image, the blue one is a text.
As you can see the ViewHolder here is square but the size is fixed and 150dp due to this code:

```
public class SquareRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // Set a square layout.

    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
}
```

The xml of the ViewHolder of the RecyclerView's adaptern being

```
        <listadoProgramas.SquareRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:listSelector="@color/fondo_contenido">
<io.leocad.view.WebCachedImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/titulo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco"
        android:background="@color/color_fondo_texto_imagen"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
        </listadoProgramas.SquareRelativeLayout>
```

I've tried setting on the on measure the following:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // Set a square layout.
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int widthScreen = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    int width = widthScreen/2;
    this.setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
    super.onMeasure(width, width);
}
```

And the result is the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/re5Xf.png
Now the ViewHolder is not square anymore and of course not half the size of the screen's width..
Any tip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `super.onMeasure(width, width);` which calls super with some garbage measure specs and it will set a new measured dimensions, overriding yours.

Instead, either don't call super or call super with proper measure specs obtained from [MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html).

Comment: Thanks! This helped me!  
Here is what I've done:  
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {  
        ...  
        int widthScreen = displaymetrics.widthPixels;  
        int newWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(widthScreen/2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);  
        this.setMeasuredDimension(newWidthMeasureSpec, newWidthMeasureSpec);  
        super.onMeasure(newWidthMeasureSpec, newWidthMeasureSpec);  
    }

Comment: Use MeasureSpec. EXACTLY instead of AT_MOST because you want it to have that height exactly. 
Also, instead of doing this, it is much better you set them in onCreateViewHolder and use RecyclerView.LayoutParams. Sorry, I should've mentioned it in the first answer. In that case, u don't have to override onMeasure and you don't need to create measure specs.

Comment: Great! That's so much simpler. Thanks!